# jQuery works on the second event, but no the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I couldn't find out why my code doesn't work correctly

I have this function:

```
function checkIt(input_name, input_value){
   if (input_name === 'firstname') {
       y = regs[0];
   } else if (input_name === 'lastname') {
       y = regs[1];
   } else if (input_name === 'phone') {
       y = regs[2];
   } else if (input_name === 'mail') {
       y = regs[3];
   } else {
       y = regs[4];
   }
   z = input_value.match(y1);

   if (z !== null) {
       rez = true;
   } else {
       rez = false;
   }

   return rez;
}
```

and then im doing this:

```
$(document).on("blur", "input[name=firstname]", function(){
    p = $(this).prop("name");
    q = $(this).val();
    r = checkIt(p, q);
    if (r) {
         // something
    } else {
         // something
    }
});
```

and my problem is that my code doesn't work on first blur. it's starting executing on second blur and does everything perfecty... :/

Comment: Just one thing: `z = input_value.match(y1);` Do you mean `y` instead of `y1`? BTW, why using global variables?

Comment: what does the console window tell you (hit F12)?

Comment: What is regs-array, and what is checkIt-function supposed to do, check that all required fields are filled?

Comment: thx a lot, it recorrected and working fine.. which global variable do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

try using on("blur", "input", function) without parameter name, because do u have the var p with prop of this input.

```
 $(document).on("blur", "input", function(){
        p = $(this).prop("name");
        q = $(this).val();
        r = checkIt(p, q);
        if (r) {
             // something
        } else {
             // something
        }
    });
```